# Select the same attribute in XPath and return result without repetition

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML document like this:

```
<wii>
  <game>
    <type genre="arcade" />
    <type genre="sport" />
  </game>
  <game>
    <type genre="platform" />
    <type genre="arcade" />
  </game>
</wii>
```

How to list all genres without repetition using only XPath?

Thanks.

Comment: I could provide solution but it would contain XSLT also

Comment: Tomalak's answer should give you what you want. Presumably the 2nd game element is missing it's closing tag due to copy/paste error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/wii/game/type/@genre[not(. = preceding::type/@genre)]
```

In plain English this selects any `@genre` attribute node for which there is no equally valued `@genre` node in the preceding part of the document.

The equality `=` operator, when given a plain value and a node-set, it compares the plain value to *every node* in the node-set, returning `true` only if all nodes match (*note that `!=` does not do that, it compares to the first node of the set only!*). The result must be negated with `not()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the distinct-values() function?

```
distinct-values(//type/@genre)
```

It's obviously of no use if that function isn't available to you.

[Here's a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217202613/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37606.aspx) to an approach that uses only XPath.